# Oledb connection throws visual studio JIT compiler popup when hosted on IIS asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, iis, oledb

I have a solution where i need to read values from Excel. I am using OLEDB connection to do the same. It all works fine when i run the solution in local. But when i host it in IIS i get the JIT compiler pop up when the oledb connection code is hit. Not able to figure out the problem.

Below is the OLEDB connection code :

```
     public static DataSet FirstColumn(string filename)
    {

        string filepath = filename;

        string sheetName = "First";
        //Oledb connection to generate excel in temporary folder on server
        string connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + filepath + "';Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\"";
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter objDA = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            ("select * from [" + sheetName + "$]", conn);
            DataSet excelDataSet = new DataSet();
            objDA.Fill(excelDataSet);
            return excelDataSet;
        }
```

The popup has an option to Debug or continue. When i debug i get "An unhandled win32 exception occurred in w3wp.exe"

Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: IIS is running on the remote machine. I think during the connection open i get this error. It says something as time up.

Comment: yes i checked the log and it was time out error